Stakeholder что он делает в StartUml
Необходимо разработать диаграмму пакетов (Package diagram) в StartUML.
Хотел бы узнать есть ли нотация по этой диаграмме. Особенно интересует Viewpoints,а в нем stakeholder.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

есть ли нотация по этой диаграмме?


Stakeholder в контексте UML 2.5:
В контексте UML 2.5, Stakeholder определяется как человек, группа или организация, которая заинтересована в проекте или оказывает влияние на его успешность. Это могут быть заказчики, пользователи, разработчики, менеджеры, проектные группы и другие лица или организации, которые оказывают влияние на проект или систему. В UML 2.5 Stakeholder может быть определен как человек или группа, которая имеет интерес к системе или проекту и может воздействовать на него как положительно, так и отрицательно => источник.

Что делает Stakeholder в StarUML:
В StarUML и других инструментах моделирования Stakeholder может быть представлен как Actor (актер) в Use Case Diagram. Каждый Actor в диаграмме случаев использования (Use Case Diagram) символизирует заинтересованную сторону, которая взаимодействует с системой. Эти взаимодействия описываются через Use Cases (случаи использования), которые показывают, какие функции системы важны для каждой заинтересованной стороны (например, пользователи, заказчики, администраторы и т. д.) => источник.

Stakeholder в контексте Package Diagram:
В Package Diagram Stakeholder напрямую не отображается. Однако, если модель системы создается с учетом Viewpoints (точек зрения), Stakeholder будет учтен в контексте этих точек зрения, поскольку различные заинтересованные стороны будут иметь разные потребности и интересы. Viewpoints помогают взглянуть на систему с разных сторон, таких как архитектурная точка зрения, точка зрения разработчиков или пользователей, что может помочь в принятии решений по поводу структуры системы и взаимодействия между пакетами. В этом контексте Stakeholder может оказывать влияние на выбор элементов, которые будут включены в диаграмму пакетов, а также на организацию пакетов с учетом их интересов => источник.


Инструменты для работы с UML:
Для эффективного моделирования и разработки с использованием UML, включая работу с Stakeholder, Use Case и Package Diagrams, вы можете воспользоваться инструментами, такими как Visual Paradigm. Эти инструменты предлагают широкий функционал для создания диаграмм, управления проектами и работы с различными точками зрения => инструменты.

благодарю за ответ
